# Get Domain LogonServer in C#

Tags: c#, dns, logonserver

In a command prompt I am able to get the domain logon server by typing:

```
echo %logonserver%
```

How can I get this same result in C#?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("logonserver")

Comment: FYI- This returns a null object when running as a scheduled task under a different users identity.  Wierd